# Override dependencies of third party jar in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Like this `org.carrot2` is depending on `commons-httpclient 3.1` So how I can change this `commons-httpclient 3.1` to `HttpClient 4.1.1`. I am working in eclipse. As I want to remove 
`commons-httpclient:3.1` from those who are depending on this jar file and I want to replace with `HttpClient 4.1.1`.

So what I was trying to do.. I doubled click on this `org.carrot2` from dependency hierarchy folder and went into its pom.xml file and was trying to change `commons-httpclient 3.1` to httpclient 4.1.1 but it is not allowing me to change as backspace and delete is not working on that..

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly please ensure that the mentioned artifact *can work properly with the HttpClient 4.1.1*.

We can define "*the exclusion*" for each dependency as it is mentioned at http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions

> Exclusions explicitly tell Maven that
>   you don't want to include the
>   specified project that is a dependency
>   of this dependency (in other words,
>   its transitive dependency)
>
> **exclusions**: Exclusions contain one or
>   more exclusion elements, each
>   containing a groupId and artifactId
>   denoting a dependency to exclude.
>   Unlike optional, which may or may not
>   be installed and used, exclusions
>   actively remove themselves from the
>   dependency tree.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>the_group</groupId>
    <artifactId>the_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>the_version</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>the_apache_group</groupId>
        <artifactId>the_http_client_artifact</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>the_apache_group</groupId>
    <artifactId>the_http_client_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

I hope this may help to achieve the requirement.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: Chitsuk, thanks for replying..`<dependencies><dependency>    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId><artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId><version>3.2.0</version><exclusions>      <exclusion><groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId><artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency>  <dependency><groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId><version>4.1.1</version>  </dependency></dependencies>` so in this I am removing commonshttpclient to httpclient4.1.1 as a dependency of org.apache.solr right??

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The HttpClient 4.1.1 will be used instead.

Comment: Chitsuk, and I have already dependencies tag in my pom.xml so I should copy only this `<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId><artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId><version>3.2.0</version><exclusions> <exclusion><groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId><artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency> <dependency><groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId><version>4.1.1</version> </dependency>` right?

Comment: Chitsuk, it will automatically build everything as soon as I save it. Or I have to do something..??

Answer (score 2):

Add a dependency on HttpClient 4.1.1 to *your* POM. Maven will recognize the conflict (assuming groupId and artifactId of httpclient have not changed) between your direct dependency, and the indirect dependency, and use the newer version. (not because its the newer one, but because it is the more direct one)

And it makes sense you can't edit other people's pom files - after all, you want carrot to use the newer http client only in your program, not in all programs that use carrot ...

Comment: @meriton, how I can add dependencies on HttpClient 4.1.1.. As I want `org.carrot2` to depend on `HttpClient 4.1.1` not on `commons-httpclient 3.1`.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your pom declares the dependency on httpclient or carrot's does, it all ends up in the same classpath. And I trust you know how to add a dependency, since carrot ended up in your dependency hierarchy somehow ...

Comment: @meriton, m working on some else projects, he left this project as it is.. so that's why I have to complete this.. And I added this `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
  </dependency> ` in my pom.xml file but those who are depending on `commons-httpclient 3.1` are still depending on this..

Comment: There is a problem with the answer above - Maven will not end up using the newest dependency. Instead, it will resolve the conflict between the 2 dependencies based on smallest distance, so it will choose the one you declare locally in your own pom because it's closer than the other one.

Comment: @Eugen, thanks for replying..`<dependencies><dependency> <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId><artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId><version>3.2.0</version><exclusions> <exclusion><groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId><artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency> <dependency><groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId><version>4.1.1</version> </dependency></dependencies>` so in this I am removing commonshttpclient to httpclient4.1.1 as a dependency of org.apache.solr right??

Comment: @Eugen: I know that. I didn't say the newness was the reason why it was chosen, only that the newest was chosen. But you are right that somebody might misinterpret it, and I have therefore added a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If something depends on `HttpClient` `3.x` it will not work to substitute `4.x` since they are completely different APIs. You will get runtime errors when trying to access the code that relies on `3.x`.

Comment: hope you remember me.. As per your suggestions I started working using HttpClient 4.1.1, and I am getting new error. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551774/http-1-1-401-authorization-required-with-httpclient-4-1-1)

Comment: This might be appreciated as a comment, but it is not an answer to op's question.