# Unable to download saxon-he 9.5 with maven

Tags: maven, saxon

Maven will not retrieve saxon 9.5, because it has two conflicting dependencies on jdom.

It turns out the second dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.4</version>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

should probably have "jdom2" as artifactId.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to override this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you are right. I have raised this as a bug issue on the Saxon community site:

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2056

We will address the problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To override dependencies in maven I suggest look at the following:

[Override dependencies of third party jar in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542118/override-dependencies-of-third-party-jar-in-maven)