# Compatibility issue with latest version of Selenium Webdriver and PhantomJs

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to run my webdriver test cases using ghostdriver (Phantomjs).I have a maven project ,OS - WIN8,
Coding - JAVA 1.7 ,
Framework : testng6.8.7+maven3 and currently using the latest version of Selenium Webdriver  i.e dependency in pom.xml file .

```
 <!-- Selenium Web Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried few PhantomJs dependencies into the pom.xml file But its not compatible with latest version of Wendriver.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm not able to import

```
  **import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;**
```

But using phantomJs version 1.0.4 , I'm able to import  but that's giving error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/HasInputDevices

So what phantomjs version can i use that would be compatible with latest version of Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: I can't find this artifact from my maven browser. I use `com.github.detro:phantomjsdriver:1.2.0` for this. It includes dependecies to the selenium libraries 2.41.0

Comment: You can also visit:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706663/phantomjs-version-compatibility-with-selenium/36769777#36769777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.github.klieber:phantomjs:1.x.x` doesn't seem to be accessible anymore. You should use `com.github.detro:phantomjsdriver:1.2.0`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also use the slightly older 1.1.0 version

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Version 1.2.0 depends on the 2.41.0 selenium libraries and version 1.1.0 has the 2.39.0 dependency.

The otherwise accessible `com.github.klieber:phantomjs-maven-plugin:0.4` doesn't provide the classes `PhantomJSDriver` and `PhantomJSDriverService`.

[Override dependencies of third party jar in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542118/override-dependencies-of-third-party-jar-in-maven) shows a way to override the version of selenium libraries to use the latest one.

Comment: :- Yeah , Its working fine . But after using latest version i.e 1.2.0 . Tests are getting hanged up .Logs are :-  [INFO  - 2014-09-24T10:51:28.988Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous
 Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2014-09-24T10:56:28.986Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous
 Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
[INFO  - 2014-09-24T11:01:28.999Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous
 Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW

Comment: I can't help you with this one.

Comment: You better to use phantomjsdriver 1.2.1 with latest Selenium version 2.53.0 .   <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
<artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>