# PhantomJS version compatibility with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser

I could not use Selenium WebDriver (a.k.a Selenium 2) 2.53.0 with PhantomJS 1.2.0.
Is there any workaround? I had to use WebDriver 2.41.0 instead of latest version (2.53.0).

Comment: Are you talking about the Java language bindings? What PhantomJS version did you use (I don't mean the PhantomJS/GhostDriver library version which is 1.2.0 in your case)?

Comment: Yes, phantomJS for Java

Comment: And what's your PhantomJS version? Have you tried another?

Comment: PhantomJS version was 1.2.0. I already mentioned. Your question is not clear to me?

Comment: [PhantomJS 1.2.0 is extremely old](http://phantomjs.org/releases.html) and you can't even use it with Selenium, because it has no integrated GhostDriver. So you could have a version starting with 1.8. What I mean is the actual PhantomJS binary. Either way, I wanted you to provide a version so that others may help you. I don't care for this issue.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand you, I was telling about the phantomJS jar (maven artifact) not the binary.


http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/detro/phantomjsdriver/

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: phantomjs is now discontinued please use jbrowserdirver for headless testing

Comment: @Ripon Al Wasim
Yes. using Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar is provided with Selenium-2.53.0. If phantomjsdriver-1.2.0 is not worked with Selenium-2.53.0 you can use phantomjsdriver-1.2.1 . Dependency code for the pom.xml should be as below:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
<artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If you use java project instead of maven project set the phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar in classpath

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me.
I dug the repository and found 1.3.0 in the same repository you mentioned: com.codeborne.

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/codeborne/phantomjsdriver/.

1.2.1 uses the 2.44.0
and
1.3.0 uses the 2.53.0

Comment: I have used phantomjs 1.2.1 with Selenium 2.53.0. It worked for me well. Thanks to mention the version phantomjs1.3.0

Comment: phantomjsdriver 1.2.0 is also working with selenium-java 2.53.0 for me:
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
 <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Yes you can use it but selenium-remote-driver will be replaced with an older version. If you use maven, you can observe it. And than if you instantiate Firefox Driver object, it will generate error. 1.3.0 does not have this problem.

Comment: Is 1.3.0 the latest version?

Comment: May be yes. You gave me the repository URL and I just did not check any other repo. :-)